# How to include setup.py in the built distribution

Tags: python

I have a typical project structure that looks as follows:

```
EngineEmulator        
    ship
        engine
            emulator
            mapping
            __init__.py
        tests
            emulator
            mapping
            __init__.py           
        setup.py
        MANIFEST.in
        setup.cfg
        README.rst
```

My setup.py looks as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
   name='Engine',
   version=1.0.0,
   description='Engine Project',      
   packages=find_packages(
   exclude=["*.tests", "*.tests.*", "tests.*", "tests"]),
   install_requires =['pycrypto', 
                      'kombu >=1.1.3'],
   author='Demo',
   author_email='demo@eliza.net'
   license='MIT',
   classifiers=[
    'Topic :: Demo Engine',
    'Development Status:: 3 - Iteration',
    'Programming Language :: Python -2.6'
]
```

)

My setup.cfg looks as follows:

```
[egg_info]
tag_build = .dev
tag_svn_revision = 1

[rotate]
#keep last 15 eggs, clean up order
match = .egg
keep = 15
```

And My MANIFEST.in looks as follows:

```
include README.rst
include setup.py
recursive-include engine *
```

When I run `python setup.py bdist` the tar file it generates does not include the setup.py file. 
When I run pip install  it complains the setup.py is missing. 
However when I did `python setup.py sdist`, it generates the tar file that has the setup.py.
Any idea why?

Comment: https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-your-own-project

Comment: @NedDeily I have already all the components outlined in the link. I also get a built distribution that includes all the files except setup.py so when I run `pip install <generated_tar>` I end up with an error saying the setup.py file is missing.

Comment: A dumb `bdist` doesn't include a `setup.py` because it's not needed: `setup.py` is not installed as part of a Distutils bdist distribution, basically it describes how to make a `bdist` from an `sdist`.

Comment: @NedDeily When I run pip install <generated Tar> on a target machine I get `setup.py missing error`. Googling led me to believe that pip cannot install if setup.py is missing.

Comment: Don't try to ship a dumb `bdist` for general installation with `pip` especially for a pure Python one. A dumb `bdist` only applies to a particular kind of Python installation, the kind you used to generate it.  Use an `sdist`.  Or use a smart bdist format like wheels.

Comment: Is there any way I can specify to setuptool to add setup.py? I already tried include setup.py in MANIFEST.in but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pip [does not install Distutils dumb `bdist` format distributions](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/30). A more general distribution format is the `sdist` format which generally can be "built" for installation with any Python instance.  An `sdist` is what would typically be uploaded to PyPI, particularly for pure Python distributions, e.g. contain no C code that would require a compiler on the target system.  Current versions of pip can also install [`wheels`](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_wheel.html), a smart `bdist` format which can include pure Python distributions or impure ones targeted at specific platforms.

Comment: Thanks Ned. I do have a possibility of adding a c extensions later. For now I followed the step in [here](http://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). When I run pip install in my site packages I only get a Engine-1.0.0-dist-info directory. No  built sources are transferred. Any pointer what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: First, get a working `sdist` that installs properly: `python setup.py sdist && pip install dist/Engine-1.0.0.dev-r0.tar.gz`.  Then try building a wheel with `bdist_wheel`: `python setup.py bdist_wheel && pip install dist/Engine-1.0.0.dev_r0-py2-none-any.whl`.  After fixing the various typos in your `setup.py` file, I had no trouble building either and they both installed the `engine` package as expected.  Make sure you have a current version of `pip` installed, too: `pip -V` -> `pip 1.5.6`.

Comment: Thanks Ned. I had a lower version of pip as well as some other issues. Finally got it working. One thing that I discovered though bdist_wheel does not compile (self.compile=False in bdist_wheel.py, run()), so it does not generate .pyc files. I had to set the compile option to tru by creating a custom command class extending install_lib and setting the self.compile to True to install function before calling the install of the super.